# Connecting to a non-local SQL Server database in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database that is not local. I have the *Data Source* and *Initial Catalog* - no issues. But need to change *Integrated Security* to False and insert SQL Server credentials.

Does anyone have any idea how put that in the connection string?

Also, does anyone know how to handle *SecureStrings*?

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim pwd As New SecureString("Password")
Dim cred As New SqlCredential("Username", pwd)
Dim sql As New SqlConnection("Data Source=OnlineServer;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what I needed to do and how to handle secure strings.

Here is a code snippet for anyone who struggles in the future:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Security 
Public Module secure
    Public Function sql()
        Dim pass As String = "Password"
        Dim pwd As SecureString = New SecureString()
        For Each ch As Char In pass
            pwd.AppendChar(ch)
        Next
        pwd.MakeReadOnly()
        Dim cred As New SqlCredential("SQL_Login", pwd)
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Server=Database_Name;Initial Catalog=Database_Address;Integrated Security=False", cred)
        Return conn
    End Function
End Module

Public Class sqlCommunications
    Dim sql As New SqlConnection
    Dim sqlcom As New SqlCommand
    Public Sub start()
        sql = secure.sql
        sqlcom.Connection = sql
        sql.Open()
        sql.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at here: [SQL Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to hopefully find which one you need. This will give you the basics.

To make the SQL account credentials confidential, you should encrypt the `<connection strings>` section in the web.config. to do so:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "OnlineServer" -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

Retrieving your connection string using ConfigurationManager will automatically decrypt the string

```
Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

Here is a [Microsoft Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx) that explains it further.